ping between aws ec2 instances terraform - Error: Cycle
I have some custom vms created with for_each with generated key files for each vm
I want to run a script that runs ping between them in a round-robin fashion, for ex for 3 vms:
vm0 ping vm1; 
vm1 ping vm2;
vm2 ping vm0

Terraform configuration:
resource "aws_key_pair" "this" {
  for_each   = var.vms
  key_name   = "ssh-key-${each.key}"
  #count = "${length(var.vms)}"
  #key_name   = "ssh-key-${keys(var.vms)[count.index]}"
  public_key = tls_private_key.this[each.key].public_key_openssh
}


resource "aws_instance" "vm" {  
  for_each      = var.vms
  instance_type = each.value["instance_type"]
  ami           = each.value["ami"]
  subnet_id     = aws_subnet.public_subnet.id
  key_name      = aws_key_pair.this[each.key].key_name
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  vpc_security_group_ids  = [aws_security_group.ssh_sg.id]
  
  tags = {
      Name = "${each.key}"
  }
  
  #Using remote-exec to run scripts on the VM after creation
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      user        = "ec2-user"  # or "ubuntu", depending on your AMI
      private_key = file("${aws_key_pair.this[each.key].private_key}")  # Ensure you are securely managing private keys
      host        = self.public_ip
    }

    #Commands are executed on each VM to ping the next in a round-robin fashion
    inline = [
      "sleep 10",  # Wait a bit for the network to be fully ready
      "ping -c 4 ${aws_instance.vm[(each.key + 1) % length(var.vms)].public_ip}"
    ]
  }
}

terraform plan fails with the following error:
Planning failed. Terraform encountered an error while generating this plan.

╷
│ Error: Cycle: aws_instance.vm["vm_1"], aws_instance.vm["vm_0"], aws_instance.vm["vm_2"]
│


Would you mind explaining why do you need to ping between instances?

it is a test assignment, it has no real production use

I understand that, but what is the use case? I'm asking because there might be an easier way to do what you want.

it must be done in terraform, it's a mandatory requirement

I didn't ask about having to do it in terraform or not, rather what is it you need to achieve.

The problem is that you're creating a cycle in inline meta-argument in the provisioner section.
If you think about it, terraform cannot execute this script, since in order to ping vm3, we need to initialize it. In order to initialize it, we need to initialize vm1 since it is required in provisioner block for vm3. To initialize vm1, we need to initialize vm2 for the same reason, but to initialize vm2, terraform need to initialize vm3 and here we go.
Really, the core of the problem is that you're trying to use the terraform for what it is not designed for - these scripts that launch a process of continues ping pong between vms are not a part of the trackable state. Terraform has no idea what is the implication of these scripts and therefore cannot manage/replace/undo this changes on VMs. This is why provisioners are highly discuraged.
To solve the problem:
In your case, I would try to set it up via either

Take advantage of user_data of AWS EC2 isntances, not a remote-exec provisioner. You can sue a tftpl templates to make it dynamic or implement the logic of peers discovering inside the scripts themselves.

Or, what I think is significantly better, is to produce outputs in your terraform code and feed them to a tool like Ansible, to allow it to configure the servers with given scripts. It is for sure possible in CI/CD pipeline, but can be a bit more time-consuming to set up.


Hope it helped, have a nice day!

you're right, terraform is not the tool for this, it is part of an assignment given to me and must be done in terraform, i guess they want to see how i can solve something unconventional like this. I'd appreciate some code samples
